# Overriding layered navigation block

Tags: magento2

I just want add a custom function in layered navigation block `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation`

the function :

```
public function getActiveFilters()
{
   $filters = $this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters();
   if (!is_array($filters)) {
        $filters = [];
   }
   return $filters;
}
```

ive tried to create custom module to override block with preferences as well as plugin, but no luck its not working.

at first try, im using preference. I use this code in

`Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Navigation" />
</config>
```

and create block in my custom module

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Navigation extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
{
    /**
     * Retrieve active filters
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getActiveFilters()
    {
        $filters = $this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters();
        if (!is_array($filters)) {
            $filters = [];
        }
        return $filters;
    }
}
```

but its not working, as well as using plugin to override block.

am I missing something?
and what is the best way to override block?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you find anything then/

Answer (score 0):

This is because `\Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation::getActiveFilters` does't exist.

The method in your question appears to be from `\Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State::getActiveFilters` so you would need to update your `di.xml` to reflect this. It is also recommended to use [interceptors](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) (plugins) over rewrites

**`Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Module::filterActiveLayeredNavigationItems" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\LayeredNavigation\Navigation\State"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**`app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Block/LayeredNavigation/Navigation/State.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\LayeredNavigation\Navigation;

class State
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State $subject
     * @param array                                             $result
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetActiveFilters(
        \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State $subject,
        $result = []
    ) {
        $result = $this->doYourLogic($result);

        return $result;
    }
}
```